# Triggering LocationListener's event manually

Tags: android, android-location

Is there a way to manually trigger the code inside a `LocationListener`'s `onLocationChanged` method? It should receive a `Location` object with the last known location, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure thing, if it's your `LocationListener` - `onLocationChanged()` is a public method; just call it with whatever Location object you have on hand (maybe have your location listener cache it somewhere, or use `LocationManager`'s [`getLastKnownLocation`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation%28java.lang.String%29) method to grab the last location seen from a specific provider and call `onLocationChanged()` with that).

Comment: This looks right, but since the class is inside another class and I want to call it from elsewhere, I opted for moving the code to a public function of the superclass, and calling that from the listener. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `setTestProviderLocation` method of the `LocationManager` to mock new locations and have the `onLocationChanged` method of the registered listeners called when you want.

You should check the [reference page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html). You also have an example [here](http://markmail.org/message/koo6pdhusseubuth).

Comment: I don't really want to do mock locations. I want to trigger the code inside the listener when other stuff happens in the app.

Comment: If you want to execute the code completely unrelated to location changes you should not have that code in a location listener. My answer states how to manually trigger the registered listeners without any actual location change.

Comment: Hmm you're probably right. I just thought there might be a way of doing this (since it's not *completely* unrelated to location changes)

Comment: If you just want to execute the method follow Yoni Samlan's advice, but you should *definitely* change your question title, as it says that you want to "trigger the event", and this only happens on location change.